# Problem with pure definition in Applicative

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm a Haskell beginner and I've to solve a worksheet question and this time I'm really stuck. Help!:))

I've to work out the instances for some monad starting with functor up to monad and i can't figure out the pure in the Applicative instance. I don't want to post all the code of the program but I think thoe following should illustrate the problem:

This is given code, can't be changed:

```
class (Semigroup a, Monoid a) => Log a where
    logMsg :: String -> a

newtype Logger l a = Logger (a,l)
    deriving Show

logMsgM :: Log l => String -> Logger l ()
logMsgM s = Logger ((), logMsg s)
```

These are the instances I'm working on:

```
instance (Log l) => Functor (Logger l) where 
    fmap g (Logger (a, l)) = Logger ((g a), l)


instance (Log l) => Applicative (Logger l) where 
    pure ???????????????????
    (<*>) (Logger (g,l)) (Logger (a,_)) = Logger ((g a), l)

instance (Log l) => Monad (Logger l) where 
    return                                              = pure
    (>>=) (Logger (a,l)) g                              = (g a)
    (>>)  x y                                           = x >>= \_ -> y
```

With the pure I'm stuck. pure =  Logger produces infinte type error a ~ (a,l) and all attempts to tweak with input paranmeters end up in either unknown variable error, or strange type errors with type variables with tailing zeros and such stuff. I tried so much, that's difficult to post the error messages in a more sensible way.
I don't undertand what's going on. This is based on a introduction lecture, so I know about the basic concepts. I just can't handle this newtype definition correctly with the function declaration (I think...), in particular this subsumption of two parameters into one (pair). I do understand (or maybe better wording: "I can follow") the typical examples with cases in type defintions or newtypes, such as maybe , either, or other with same number or more parameters at the right side. However, maybe, I'm wrong with this assumption and I'm making a fallacy somewhere I don't see at all.

Btw, the whole code compiles when writing pure = return, but the program produces a stack overflow (smile). I think this is no wonder as return = puer and pure = return may well compile but makes no sense, right!?

Thanx for help :)

Answer (score 6):

`Logger` is a type more commonly known as the [`Writer` monad](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-21-writer-monad.html). The idea is that if you have a `Logger l a`, with `l` being a `Semigroup`, then if you run a `Logger l a` and then another `Logger l b`, the result will have the two `l`s next to each other (i.e. concatenated using the `Monoid` operation). That is:

```hs
Logger (1,"test1") >> Logger (2,"test2")   ==   Logger (2,"test1" <> "test2")
```

Given this, `pure a` will just be `Logger (a, something)`, where `something` is a value which doesn’t have any effect when concatenated. But now look at the typeclass declarations:

```hs
class (Semigroup a, Monoid a) => Log a where ...
instance (Log l) => Applicative (Logger l) where ...
```

So in `Applicative (Logger l)`, `l` must be a `Monoid`, so it must have an identity value `mempty`! This gives us `pure a = Logger (a, mempty)`, which simply returns `a` without affecting the log.

---

However, there is still a problem. If we have `Logger (a1,l1) >>= \x -> Logger (a2,l2)`, or `Logger (a1,l1) <*> Logger (a2,l2)`, we want to concatenate `l1 <> l2` in the result. But your current implementation doesn’t do that! So you’ll need to change it to satisfy this property. Since I don’t want to solve the whole worksheet for you, I’m leaving this as an exercise; however, if you become stuck, you may want to consult the link at the top of this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations, this really helps a lot. And thank you also for your hint concerning >>=, right now I don't see it, but will try to work it out my own. I always try to get through the tasks without help as far as possible. That's the way to link concepts with practice, right? It's like math, you may know all axioms, sentences and whatsoever, but, without practice, even though may fail severly in applying them correctly and meaningfully. :)

Comment: @rebit “I always try to get through the tasks without help as far as possible.” Yes, that’s very much my philosophy as well; it’s the reason why I set that final task as an exercise instead of providing the answer directly. (It also means that your question was a pleasure to answer, as you provided enough of your prior work that I could easily see the problem.) I also have the same opinion about maths as you; especially when reading textbooks, I often understand all the concepts but fall down in their application.

Comment: @rebit And as for `>>=`: the idea is that if you have a `Logger (a1,l1)` (which logs `l1`), and then follow it with a `Logger (a2,l2)` (which logs `l2`), the combined value should be something which logs `l1` then `l2`. This should hold true whether you combine the values with `<*>`, `>>=` or `>>` (so it’s not just `>>=`; you’ll actually have to redo all of these functions). To combine these values, you can use the `Semigroup` operator `<>` (as that’s what `Semigroup` is for). (continued in next comment as I’m running out of characters…)

Comment: @rebit … The identity for this operator is of course `mempty` (as defined by the `Monoid` laws), so the value of something which does not add to the log is `Logger (a,mempty)` — which is the definition of `pure`, thus providing an additional explanation of why I defined it that way in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Adapted pure to what you wrote and changed the definition of <*> to "(<*>) (Logger (g,l1)) (Logger (x,l2)) = Logger ((g x), (l1 <> l2))". Seems to work :D. And I think, I got the point for the logging as meant to be implemented here (fibonacci recursively): As LogMsgM puts out "Logger ((),"logging string")", recursively calling LogMsgM in a do block, just the logging strings are concatenated with >> (no "left arrow" in do), the way of which is defined in <*>. >>= takes the (numeric) value from the context, which then is fed into the next recursion cycle. (next...)

Comment: So, here in fact the function handed to fmap is (+), summing up all fibonacci elements in "return" at the end of the do block. Right? Wow, this is quite abstract, if you are accustomed to imperative algorithm thinking...

Comment: @rebit I’m glad you understand the motivation for this implementation now! However, I’ve never heard of writing the Fibonacci sequence using the Writer monad; that does seem excessively abstract, even for Haskell. It does sound fascinating though; if it’s online, do you have a link to the code? (Also by the way, you can insert code blocks in comments by surrounding text in backticks \`like this\`; it’s just a bit easier to read than surrounding it by double quotes.)